# Get orientation of object in OpenTK C#

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl, opentk, opengl-compat

I used to rotate an object in multiple stages but cant figure out how to get the actual orientation (Eular angles) of object.

```
GL.Rotate(rotateCAx, new Vector3d(1, 0, 0));
GL.Rotate(rotateCAy, new Vector3d(0, 1, 0));
GL.Rotate(rotateCAz, new Vector3d(0, 0, 1));
GL.Rotate(xRot, new Vector3d(1, 0, 0));
GL.Rotate(yRot, new Vector3d(0, 1, 0));
GL.Rotate(zRot, new Vector3d(0, 0, 1));
```

What is the orientation of object now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to change the order of the angles, when you apply them tho the current matrix:

```
GL.Rotate(rotateCAz, new Vector3d(1, 0, 0));
GL.Rotate(rotateCAy, new Vector3d(0, 1, 0));
GL.Rotate(rotateCAx, new Vector3d(0, 0, 1));
GL.Rotate(zRot, new Vector3d(1, 0, 0));
GL.Rotate(yRot, new Vector3d(0, 1, 0));
GL.Rotate(xRot, new Vector3d(0, 0, 1));
```

Either read back the current matrix from the GPU:

```
Matrix4 currentModelView;
GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ModelviewMatrix, out currentModelView);
```

or calculate a transformation matrix with the same rotations:

```cs
Matrix4 currentModelView = 
    Matrix4.CreateRotationX(xRot * (float)Math.PI / 180.0f) *
    Matrix4.CreateRotationY(yRot * (float)Math.PI / 180.0f) *
    Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(zRot * (float)Math.PI / 180.0f) * 
    Matrix4.CreateRotationX(rotateCAx * (float)Math.PI / 180.0f) *
    Matrix4.CreateRotationY(rotateCAy * (float)Math.PI / 180.0f) *
    Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(rotateCAz * (float)Math.PI / 180.0f);
```

Convert the rotation component of the [`Matrix4`](https://opentk.net/api/OpenTK.Matrix4.html) to a [`Quaternion`](https://opentk.net/api/OpenTK.Quaternion.html):

```
Quaternion q = currentModelView.ExtractRotation();
```

Compute the [Pitch, yaw, and roll](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch,_yaw,_and_roll) angles from the `Quaternion`. An algorithm fro that can be found at [Maths - Conversion Quaternion to Euler](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/). I've used the [OpenGL Mathematics](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) implementation for [`glm::pitch`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00663.html#ga7603e81477b46ddb448896909bc04928), [`glm::yaw`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00663.html#ga8da38cdfdc452dafa660c2f46506bad5) and [`glm::roll`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00663.html#ga0cc5ad970d0b00829b139fe0fe5a1e13):

```cs
const double epsi = 0.0001;
double y = 2.0 * (q.Y * q.Z + q.W * q.X);
double x = q.W * q.W - q.X * q.X - q.Y * q.Y + q.Z * q.Z;

double pitch = (Math.Abs(q.X) < epsi && Math.Abs(q.Y) < epsi) ? 2.0 * Math.Atan2(q.X, q.W) : Math.Atan2(y, x);
double yaw = Math.Asin(Math.Min(Math.Max(-2.0 * (q.X * q.Z - q.W * q.Y), -1.0), 1.0));
double roll = Math.Atan2(2.0 * (q.X * q.Y + q.W * q.Z), q.W * q.W + q.X * q.X - q.Y * q.Y - q.Z * q.Z);
```

The angles `pitch`, `yaw` and `roll` correspond to the current rotations around the x, y and z axis (in view space).

```
float rot_x = pitch * 180.0f / (float)Math.PI; 
float rot_y = yaw   * 180.0f / (float)Math.PI; 
float rot_z = roll  * 180.0f / (float)Math.PI;
```

Comment: value of yaw, pitch and roll abruptly changes and continue cycling between -3 and +3. Even a change of single degree in angle changes it from -1 to 2.5